# How can I get Validators from the formControl directly?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-forms

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have an email field, and I added two validators(required, email), I want to check validation status on the `input event` to call API check dose a member of my system when it's valid, if it's `invalid` don't to call API and don't show error message on the page.

I will show error message on blur event(focusOut email's input),firstly I used `formControl.validator(formControl)` to trigger validators and check `formControl.valid`,I got valid status successful but it will show error message on the page because I subscribed `statsuChange` to show an error message when status equal to `invalid.`

currently, I save validators in a variable and pass to `initEmailChaingeEvent()` to check validation status without statusChange event.
It's can work, but I think it's not a good way, here's an example of my implementation:

[live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-can-i-get-validators-from-the-formcontrol-directly)

```js
export class AppComponent {
  public sampleForm: FormGroup;

  @ViewChild('emailElm')
  emailElm: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm();
  }

  initForm() {
    const emailValidtors = [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.email
    ]

    const emailFC = new FormControl(null, {
      validators: emailValidtors,
      updateOn: 'blur'
    });
    //
    this.sampleForm = new FormGroup({
      'email': emailFC
    });
    //
    this.initEmailChaingeEvent({
      emailFC: emailFC,
      validtors: emailValidtors
    });
    //
    this.sampleForm.valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
      console.log('_blue event:valueChanges', val)
    });
    //
    this.initShowErrorMsgEvent({
      fc: emailFC
    });
  }

  private initEmailChaingeEvent(arg: {
    emailFC: FormControl,
    validtors: any[]
  }) {
    fromEvent(this.emailElm.nativeElement, 'input')
      .pipe(debounceTime(500))
      .subscribe((event: Event) => {
        const currentEmail = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
        // check is valid
        // **quention** : how can I get validtors from fromcontrol self 
        // if I use  arg.emailFC.validator(arg.emailFC) to ehcek status , it will trigger oberservable in initShowErrorMsgEvent(),
        //  but I just want to got valid result , I don't want to show error msg on UI at this time

        for (const validator of arg.validtors) {
          const inValid = validator(arg.emailFC);
          if (inValid) {
            console.log('input event:invalid', currentEmail);
            return;
          }
        }
        // **do sometheng when all valid**
        console.log('input event:call API , email:',currentEmail );
      });
  }

  private initShowErrorMsgEvent(arg: {
    fc: FormControl,
  }) {
    arg.fc.statusChanges
      .subscribe((status) => {
        // console.log('status' , status);
        if (status === 'INVALID') {
          // show error msg....
          console.log('_show error msg by antoher component');
        }
      });
  }
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="sampleForm">
  <input formControlName="email" #emailElm >
</form>
```

Comment: I updated my question, I check input value on input event and show error message on blur event because I was set `updateOn:blur'` on FormControl, `.valid` or `.invalid` will not trigger on the input event

Comment: So in summary, you want to send the form to an api when the form is valid automatically?

Comment: when email field valid, I want to send it to API to check is a member of my system

Comment: So the question is on how to do an email validation? Or just sending the form once it's valid?

Comment: when user type their email => check by my formcontrol's validation => call API to check dose a member if it's valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks everyone give me more idea,I fixed it through [formControl's validator](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#validator) property,it's my modifyed list:

- only pass value to validators avoid trigger statusChange emitter

[live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/answer1-how-can-i-get-validators-from-the-formcontrol-direc?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```js
private initEmailChaingeEvent(arg:{
   emailFC : FormControl,
   ....
}) {
  ...
  const inValid = arg.emailFC.validator({
      value: currentEmail
    }
    as any);
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You over-complicated the task.
First, declare your form, and control validators. If you compose a validator from a list of validators, they will be checked in order of definition. So, first the required, then "if it's valid email", and last you custom validator will check if it's unique

```
 ....
 this.emailForm = this.fb.group({
       emailAddress: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email, uniqueEmailValidator()])]
 });
 ...
```

Then you create your custom validator for checking the user email by the API. More info on custom validators: [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators)

```
function uniqueEmailValidator(){
    ...
}
```

Comment: does this solution prevent StatusChange from being triggered to show validation error messages?

Comment: The validators are checked in order of definition, and the next validator isn't checked if the current failes. First time. validators are checked on 'blur', if an error occures then on every keydown event.

Comment: I create a [live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ans-zsolttolvalyp-how-can-i-get-validators-from-the-formcontrol) for this solution, but it's not working on that you say: `the validators checked in order of definition.` I try to find checked in order in [angular source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/41698bf5fdf9a51f1250875af63b0ef32f87b0e3/packages/forms/src/validators.ts#L202), but I still got nothing, Does my example code is wrong?

Comment: I will post a working example later this week. I had a lot on my head recently, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot going on here that needs some work. First off, I'd subscribe to the formValue changes of the control instead of using an Observable on the native element.

```
this.sampleForm.get('email').valueChanges.subscribe((event) => {
    // CODE IN HERE
}
```

ValueChanges is a property on the formControl that emits an event when the value changes. https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl

Next, to access the validators, you can simply check the form control if it is valid.

```
this.sampleForm.get('email').valid();
```

If any validator is invalid, this will be false, if all validators are valid, it will be true.

EDIT:

From your comment, sounds like you want a debounceTime pipe in there:

```
this.sampleForm.get('email').valueChanges
.pipe(debounceTime(500), distinctUntilChanged())
.subscribe((event) => {
    if (this.sampleForm.get('email').valid) {
         // Your API logic here
    }
}
```

DebounceTime basically delays the event from being processed and will throw out any pending events in the queue.

> debounceTime delays values emitted by the source Observable, but drops previous pending delayed emissions if a new value arrives on the source Observable. http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-debounceTime

Comment: the answer is good, but  the trigger timing is not I want,  as I said before I set the blue event emits valureChanges, but I want to get the valid result on input event and don't trigger statusChange because I don't want to show an error message if it's invalid

Comment: @ChunbinLi: I'm not really sure what you're saying so here I apologize if I'm saying the wrong thing. You don't need to display an error message, and you don't have to take an action until the control is valid. It sounds like what you're looking for from your comment is a debounceTime pipe, I've updated my answer with this logic in place.

Comment: I added an image to describe it, I have two events (blur, input) on email field,debounceTime can't validate and don't show the message on initEmailChaingeEvent() function

Comment: @ChunbinLi why are you using onBlur here, is there a particular reason?

Comment: project manager want to show error when leaving to other fields to improve User Experience

Comment: @ChunbinLi I understand the problem you’re trying to solve, just not your approach. Is there a reason to use onBlur instead of formChanges?

Comment: how to use formChanges instead of OnBlur?

Comment: @ChunbinLi sorry, I meant subscribing to valueChanges

Comment: I set formControl's updateOn: blue, so valueChanges will be trigger by blue Event